# Parameters for a foldleft on list of futures

Tags: scala

I would like to experiment foldleft on Futures. I start with a simple/dumb example as a worksheet:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val list = (1 to 10).toList
def doubleFuture(i: Int) = Future { println(i);i }

val twoFutures = list map doubleFuture //returns List[Future[Int]]
val res = (twoFutures foldLeft(List[Int]())
    ((theList:List[Int], aFuture:Future[Int]) =>
    {
      theList :+ 1
    }))
```

The compiler is not happy with it and indicates:

```
Error:(11, 48) type mismatch;
 found   : (List[Int], scala.concurrent.Future[Int]) => List[Int]
 required: Int
    ((theList:List[Int], aFuture:Future[Int]) =>
                                          ^
```

I don't understand why the second argument of the foldleft function is not of type Future[Int] as twoFutures is of type `List[Future[Int]]`.
What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a period (`.`) after the list to tell compiler that the block or parentheses after the parentheses be bound to `foldLeft` instead of `twoFutures`:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object FutureList {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val list = (1 to 10).toList
    def doubleFuture(i: Int) = Future { println(i); i }

    val twoFutures = list map doubleFuture //returns List[Future[Int]]

    val res = twoFutures.foldLeft(List[Int]())(
      (theList, aFuture) => theList :+ 1)

    println(res)

    // Uncomment these lines to unfold the mystery
    //    val theList = List[Int]()
    //    val aFuture = Future[Int](0)
    //    twoFutures((theList: List[Int], aFuture: Future[Int]))

  }
}
```

To explain what it means, you can uncomment the three commented lines above. You will see the same compilation error as you will get without the period after `twoFutures` list:

```
 Multiple markers at this line
    - type mismatch; found : (List[Int], scala.concurrent.Future[Int]) required: 
     Int
    - type mismatch; found : (List[Int], scala.concurrent.Future[Int]) required: 
     Int
```

### Output

```
2
4
1
3
5
6
8
10
7
9
List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: This reminds me of the ; after the if when I was doing C++ and that I could not see :-) - I think the compiler could be a bit more helpful here. But you were instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This the solution use the dot notation on the fold left i.e.

```
val res = (twoFutures.foldLeft(List[Int]())
    ((theList:List[Int], aFuture:Future[Int]) =>
    {
      theList :+ 1
    }))
```